# Relation between Pini di Roma and Rutter Magnificat?

Tags: theory, melody

I just noticed that the closing of "Quia fecit mihi magna" from the Magnificat by John Rutter (starting at the "Sanctus") is a near-verbatim citation of a passage from movement 2 of Respighi's "Pini di Roma" ("Pini presso una catacomba"). I was just wondering, did Rutter quote Respighi directly, or are they both referencing the same melody which might be even older than that (e.g. some plainchant or anything like that)? Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have scores in front of me, but I did find something interesting while cross-referencing some Wikipedia articles.

Regarding the Rutter:

> The movement is closed by a chant-like accompanied *Sanctus, taken from the Missa cum jubilo*. ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnificat_(Rutter)#3))

And regarding the Respighi:

> A hymn is heard (specifically the Kyrie ad libitum 1, Clemens Rector; and the *Sanctus from Mass IX, Cum jubilo*), the sound rising and sinking again into some sort of catacomb, the subterranean cavern in which the dead are immured. ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pines_of_Rome#Structure))

The following excerpts show the relation very clearly:

- [Rutter](https://youtu.be/0pNSHC_iqcQ?t=5m21s)
- [Respighi](https://youtu.be/lnsbLeCffa8?t=4m19s)
- The [Sanctus](https://youtu.be/TvuQZSCKgOM?t=4s) from the Cum jubilo mass, a mass reserved for Feasts of the Virgin Mary

Nice catch!

Comment: Ugh, I could have just looked it up on Wikipedia? Now I feel stupid, that thought really never into my mind somehow. Thanks for doing it for me and for your accurate and detailed answer!